# Where do I input drush commands?

Tags: drush

I am developing a Drupal 6.28 core website from a PC and was wondering where I would make `drush` commands to update the Drupal core to 7.

I am new to Drupal and PC Development, but I assume that it is a terminal command? Can I use the Windows Command Prompt? What directory would I need to be in to successfully run `drush pm-update projects drupal-7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server (where the site lives) is not this same Windows machine, you can use a tool like Putty: http://www.putty.org/ to SSH to that box, and the putty window will serve as "terminal" from which you can use unix commands (like drush).

Answer (score 3):

Drush core does not support upgrading from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 with any of the built-in commands pm-update only supports minor updates.  You'll need the [Drush Site Upgrade](https://drupal.org/project/drush_sup) command to advance to the next major version.

Note that this command has not been tested on Windows; it would probably be safer to run the command in a Linux environment.  Use a virtual machine (e.g. virtualbox) if you do not have a dedicated Linux environment.

Doing a major upgrade from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 is a serious endevour; the Drush site-upgrade command will help you walk through the process, but it does not do all of the work for you.  The process isn't too hard if it goes smoothly, but you may run into contrib bugs that complicate the process.  An alternative method to upgrade would be to just make an equivalent Drupal 7 site from scratch, and then use [drupal-to-drupal migration](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) to move your content over.

Finally, to answer your specific question, there are a number of ways to specify the Drupal site that you would like Drush to operate on, but the easiest and most straightforward way would be to cd to the directory that contains your settings.php file (often `sites/default`).  You will also need to set up an alias (for your target Drupal site) if you use the Drush site-upgrade command; see the file [examples.aliases.drushrc.php](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php) for instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Drush has a page on it's website about writing custom drush commands ([here](http://drush.ws/docs/commands.html))

Another option would be to just write a shell script of the drush commands you want to run to execute a full update (such as disabling modules, updating modules, etc.)

Comment: That's exactly what I thought the OP was asking first, but after reading it again I think they just want to know where in the filesystem they should run the drush command from